# Does a function that gets object by value must create a temporary object with -fno-elide-constructors flag

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, move-constructor

I have edited the question after changing the c++17 to 11

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

using namespace std;
class A 
{
    public: 
    static int s;
    int t = s;
    A(){
      cout << "constructed"  << t<< endl;  
      s++;
    } 
 A (A&& a) {

    cout << "in move ctor, moving"<< a.t << " creating" << s << endl; 
     s++;
 }
 ~A() { 

     cout << "deleting"<< t << endl;
    }

};

A f1 (A a) 
{ 
    std::cout << "f1: " << endl; 
    return a; 
}
int A::s = 0;

int main() {
    f1(A()) ;
    std::cout <<  "is still alive!" << endl; 
}
```

which compiles with
 `g++  -std=c++11 -fno-elide-constructors -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out`
The output is:

```
constructed0
in move ctor, moving0 creating1
f1: 
in move ctor, moving1 creating2
deleting2
deleting1
deleting0
is still alive!
```

And i can't understand why.
If f1 receives A by value, and it is being given with a A&& object (from f2), 
 It create a temporary object "a" inside f1 function right?
If so, when exiting the temporary object (here "1") should have been destroyed, no?
 from what i can tell from the example, the temporary object is being destroyed at the end of the line, with all the other temporary objects, and not inside f1 function
So the question is:
does an object that is being created solely for a function is destroyed inside(at the end) of the function? or it is being destroyed at the end of the line creating it.
Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm sorry, but between the code segments that are unrelated to the question, and the less than favorable formatting, I'm having trouble figuring out what you find perplexing.

Comment: You are violating the rulr of 3/5/0.

Comment: Could be a conflict with `-std=c++17` which requires the function not to create a temporary for the return value.

Comment: Please post it as the answer, Thanks, c++17 "wins" -fno-elide-constructors

Comment: I don't know exactly what g++ does, so just guessing. :-)